# Google api php client - Http put request

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to create a Http put request with google-api-php-client. Oauth is working fine and I can do get requests but I just can't figure out how to do a put.

```
//While looping over my contacts
$apiClient = new ApiClient();
$apiClient->setAccessToken($this->Auth->user('google_oauth2_token'));

//Getting fresh XML data since I transformed mine into an array
$contactGetRequest = new apiHttpRequest($contact['link'][1]['@href'], 'GET', array('GData-Version' => 3.0));   
$rawContactData = $apiClient->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($contactGetRequest);

$contactXml = Xml::build($rawContactData->getResponseBody());

//Not changing anything, just trying to do a PUT request
$contactPutRequest = new apiHttpRequest($contact['link'][2]['@href'], 'PUT', array('GData-Version' => 3.0), $contactXml->asXML());
$response = $apiClient->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($contactPutRequest);
```

The error is getting is "Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not a valid input type.".

It seems that it's trying to do a POST. What is the correct way to do a PUT request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. The Content-type value has to be set in the headers parameter. I tought it was done automatically.

```
$contactPutRequest = new apiHttpRequest($contact['link'][2]['@href'], 'PUT', array('GData-Version' => 3.0, 'Content-type' => 'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=entry'), $contactXml->asXML());
```